# Is it any way possible to do text shadows with current IE9 beta CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html, shadows

So text shadows in FF and Chrome are grate. For example I have simple web page for simple video streaming server.. no shadows in IE9 for me(

my css code is like

```
p{color: #000;text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff;padding-bottom:1em}
```

so I wonder - may be there is some JS of special CSS way for creating text shadows for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter: Shadow(Color=#666666,   
            Direction=135, 
            Strength=5);
```

Try this for ie

Comment: and how to configure it for my case? I try filter: Shadow(Color=#fff,   
            Direction=0, 
            Strength=1); but it give some crap...

Comment: add a height:1em; with your filter settings lets say filter: Shadow(Color=red,Direction=0, 
            Strength=1)

Answer (score 1):

IE has shadow filter which should do what you want - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Actually not so grate for IE9=) And is there any shch thing for IE8, 7, 6? It makes letters way 2 bold before appliing smal shadow.

Comment: This should work for all IE's, however the filters are never look that great. It's up to you if you want to give the users shadows or not.I can't respond to aksarben so I will put it here. CSS3 text-shadow isn't supported in IE9 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx go half way down.

Answer (score 1):

Text shadows are standard in CSS3: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html

Comment: That doesn't mean IE9 supports/will support all CSS3 features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705.aspx

Comment: True enough. I haven't seen the IE 9 beta yet, but supposedly it's doing well on the Acid3 test.